# OpenGL/GLFW: Finding quad coordinate of a mouse click, after projection, translation and rotation of the quad

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have a quad (stretching between [-1 1] in both directions) in OpenGL. I perform an orthographic projection on its vertices, and then rotate and translate it like so:

```
glm::Mat4 map_mvp;
glm::quat rotation = glm::quat(glm::vec3(0,0,-yaw));
map_mvp = glm::toMat4(rotation) * map_mvp;
map_mvp = glm::translate(map_mvp,glm::vec3(-translate_x,translate_y,0));
map_mvp = glm::ortho(-width/map_zoom,width/map_zoom,-height/map_zoom,height/map_zoom ) * map_mvp;

glUseProgram(map_program);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(map_program, "mvp"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(map_mvp));
```

The various variables in the above code (yaw, translate_x, etc.) change over time, according to other parts of the code. My aim is to know the quad coordinates of any area of the GLFW window I am using to display it that I click on. I assumed I could just reverse the projection, but when I do that, I get coordinates which appear completely random and are not correct. The code I'm using is (in a callback for mouse clicks):

```
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
    //Find click position in the same coord system as the vertices
    int pixel_width, pixel_height, virtual_width, virtual_height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &pixel_width, &pixel_height);
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &virtual_width, &virtual_height);
    double x_world_pos, y_world_pos, x_virt_to_pix, y_virt_to_pix;
    x_world_pos =  (2 * xpos / virtual_width - 1);
    y_world_pos = - (1 - 2 * ypos / virtual_height);

        //Inverse rotation to find map position
    glm::mat4 mvp_rev_map;
    glm::quat rotation = glm::quat(glm::vec3(0,0,yaw));
    mvp_rev_map = glm::inverse(glm::ortho(-v->width/v->map_zoom,v->width/v->map_zoom,-v->height/v->map_zoom,v->height/v->map_zoom)) * mvp_rev_map;
    mvp_rev_map = glm::translate(mvp_rev_map,glm::vec3(translate_x,-translate_y,0));
    mvp_rev_map = glm::toMat4(rotation) * mvp_rev_map;

    // Find z pixel depth
    GLfloat zpixel ;
    glm::vec2 screen_pos=glm::vec2(xpos, ypos);
    glm::vec2 pixel_pos=screen_pos * glm::vec2(pixel_width, pixel_height) / glm::vec2(virtual_width, virtual_height); // note: not necessarily integer
    pixel_pos = pixel_pos + glm::vec2(0.5f, 0.5f); // shift to GL's center convention
    glReadPixels((GLint)pixel_pos.x,(GLint)pixel_height-1-pixel_pos.y,1,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT, &zpixel);

    glm::vec4 quad_pos = mvp_rev_map * glm::vec4(x_world_pos, y_world_pos, (float)zpixel, 1.0);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please?